# making a child of twenty seventeen breaks home page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to move the menu bar of the twenty seventeen theme up to the top of the page by default for all my pages. I want the parallax images on the home page to act as they still do. I don't know how to do this but I tried to copy the twenty seventeen theme to try play around with it.

As soon as I make a copy or a child of the twenty seventeen theme the home page breaks and it no longer shows the same sections as the original theme did. How does changing the name of a theme break an entire page? How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I did everything that was in there and the child theme still doesn't have the same home page as the parent theme.

Comment: You should at least post some code, to begin with: the functions.php and style.css of your child theme